# Transfer data from SQLite to SQL Server 2008 at the time of INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE in SQLite

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqlite, triggers, insert-update

I have both SQLite and SQL Server 2008 r2 to store info..

Both of them have Same DB Tables..

*For Eg :*
In SQLite I have table like below

**PlayerInfo :**

```
PlayerName  SteamID     Score
Pandian     123.34.56   100
```

In SQL Server also I have the same table with same structure...

At the time of `Insert`, `Update` or `Delete` in SQLite I want to transfer the data from SQLite to SQL Server...

Is it possible to achieve this...?

Comment: Why don't you just execute the same commands on the server?

Comment: @CL.: I have updated my SQLLite Tables by using Game Plugin...It is not possible to update the SQLSERVER tables by my plugin... so only i asked... i need SQLSERVER for my WEBSITE...

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way within SQLite to trigger something in another DBMS. They are different worlds that do not communicate. The only way to replicate changes is to replicate them in your code.